# Hardwood floor installation

Tags: hardwood-floor

I want to replace my old hardwood floors in the entire first floor including kitchen. House was built in 1930 and floors are in decent shape but squeaking everywhere...
Subfloor is made of wooden planks.  I already replaced hardwood floor the second floor hallway by removing floor and securing those wooden planks with the screws and then nailing the new hardwood floor. So far it seems really sturdier and no more squeaking.

But with the entire first floor and kitchen I'm not really sure how to approach it... Should I remove all my kitchen cabinets and then put them back? And should I also just screw all those wooden planks in the first floor and then nail hardwood floor into it, or should I install plywood on top of it or remove all the wooden planks and then just install plywood?

Comment: Plywood would be the best solution, the wooden planks will constantly give you a problems, yes you have to remove the cabinets, when nailing hardwood use the nailer designed for that, it does not nail straight down but under a angle, to stop the nails coming out

Comment: It depends—can you live with some additional floor thickness in terms of transitions?